# Centring a table content vertically and horizontally in Latex

Tags: latex

I am trying to centre the content of this table vertically and horizontally as well to make it look better.
[image]

and here is the code I am using

```
\begin{table} 
\caption{Direct vs. indirect trust management steps}
\centering
\label{table:nice_table}
\small
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{4.5cm} p{4.5cm}}

\textbf{Step} & \textbf{Direct trust} & \textbf{Indirect trust}    \\
\hline

\textbf{Trust initialization} & Neutral value &  Using recommendations   
\\
\hline

\textbf{Information collection} & Direct observation & Reputation built by other nodes 
\\
\hline 

\textbf{Trust calculating} & Trust values stored locally  &  Trust values are 
distributed over the network \\
\hline

\textbf{Decision making} & Made by the node &  Made by the node \\
\hline


\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] to your question.

Comment: There is a whole section on [LATeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) dedicated for tables.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72392164/3543233), I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For insight on how to center the table vertically and horizontally, see this LaTeX forum post: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5603

In this forum, users have used

`{c|c|c|…}`

for horizontal centering, and

`>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}`

for vertical centering in conjunction with the previous horizontal centering.

Hope this helps!